# TPL vs Async in .net?

Tags: .net-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

i didnt use TPL that much in .net 4 but i know its great for multi-core Applications

but in PDC i saw them announcing Async CTP & i only saw Async in F#

my Question is what is the difference between them & what are the best practices for each of them

thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The async features in C# 5 will *use* the TPL... which is just a library, of course. Asynchronous methods will simply make it a lot easier to *use* the TPL... given appropriate relatively-low-level async operations (e.g. "fetch a web page asynchronously" or "read a block of data asynchronously" it will be fairly easy to build higher-level asynchronous operations.

In terms of best practices - for TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) there's an interesting [white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4969771d-9855-4421-baa0-c91848db4ab0&displaylang=en). For parallel programming in general with .NET, there's a book by the Patterns and Practices group, ["Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735651590) and also Joe Duffy's book ["Concurrent Programming on Windows"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) - although the latter predates the TPL slightly.

Comment: so we can say its just a high level of abstractions?

Comment: @Saif: It depends on what exactly you mean by "it".

Comment: meaning Async is just a higher abstraction of TPL

Comment: @Saif: I wouldn't really put it that way, to be honest... async/await is a feature which uses TPL, but it's not really an abstraction in itself.

Comment: Interesting really , i'll download the CTP now & try it :) , thanks Jon